# Couldn't find 'Rating Settings' under 'General Settings' in List Settings page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise

I have to implement rating [like the steps here](http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/12/02/how-to-use-rating-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx). 
But the problem is that I couldn't find 'Rating Settings' under 'General Settings' in List Settings page.

I tried [this](http://dxjo.net/dxit/2011/09/activate-and-enable-rating-in-sharepoint-2010/) to configure in central admin .. but no luck.

Can any one please suggest what can be done.

Comment: I enabled rating field, three default field will be added in SharePoint list view. Only one field is showing in list i.e **Rating (0-5)** rest **Rated By** and **User Ratings** is not showing. It is showing hidden mode in list view,when we are modifying any views. So can anyone please help me out to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

You have tagged the question with SharePoint Foundation so I assume you are not using SharePoint Server product.

Ratings are NOT available in SharePoint Foundation. They are available in SharePoint Server standard and enterprise version only.

See the feature comparison here: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx

**UPDATE**:

Based on your comments and link in your question, it seems looks like it should be available to you unless you started with blank site template. I just figured it out. Also check: http://the-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/01/where-is-my-rating-feature.html

You can enable RATING feature alone by following Powershell command.

```
Enable-SPFeature 915c240e-a6cc-49b8-8b2c-0bff8b553ed3 –URL http://yoururl.com
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86705/discussion-on-answer-by-ashish-patel-couldnt-find-rating-settings-under-gene).